# Notepad or JetBrains regex

Tags: regex, text, notepad++, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

My target is to convert

```
Sunday=sundat
Monday=jureq
Tuesday=tuasna
```

to:

```
"Sunday":"sundat",
"Monday":jureq",
"Tuesday":tuasna",
```

So I have to add "" signs to all key and value words, to replace = sign with : sing and add , sign to end of row. Is that possible with notepadd++ or any JetBrains IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex [`(.*)=(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/Fc9pp6/2) and replace with `"\1":"\2",`. It stores all character on each side of the equal in groups, then reinserts them. Next time try to use [regex101](https://www.regex101.com) before to find a regex, mostly for simple ones like this. You can also find many complete tutorials in which you learn to do this, just look on Google.